# Creating a small range, small baseline varying resistor

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, design, ohms-law, electrical

I am doing a design project on making a passive varying resistor device. I have a flex sensor that increases in resistance when you bend it. It has a 10k ohm nominal resistance and increase to 110k when it is a 90o degree bend. **HOWEVER**, I want my device to have a nominal resistance of 100 ohm and increase only 2-3 ohm instead.

My initial approach:
I made parallel-resistors circuits but when I get to the right nominal resistance, the resistance change is not what I want when I bend the sensor.

ONE of my important design criteria is that I want my device to be passive, so that my device will still have a desire resistance range even with it has different resistance source.

Comment: *resistance source* ??

Comment: Larry, exactly why do you want \$100\:\Omega\$, nominally, and no more than \$103\:\Omega\$? How precise must each of these be? What system is this going into which requires this kind of approach? (It makes no sense on the surface and you've provided ZERO information about your thinking process here. We need to hear more about how you are arriving at this, as well as the details of accuracy and precision.)

Comment: Impossible. your sensor changes conductance by less than 0.1 millisiemens , you cant promote that to a 3 millisiemens change by passive means.

Comment: if you connect 33 of those sensors in parallel, then you have a starting point

Comment: 0.3millisiemens actually. -- maybe only needs 4 sensors in parallel

Comment: XY problem smell.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to put 101 ohms in parallel with the 10 k resistor. Then the net resistance is 100 ohms. If the 10k rose to 110k the resistance only becomes 100.9 ohms i.e. a change of 0.9 ohm sat on top of a base of 100 ohm.

If the change needs to be 3 ohms then choose a resistor higher than 101 ohms (say) 330 ohms for a guess. Now the base resistance is 319.45 ohms and rises to  329 ohms, a change of about ten ohms.

You can do the calculations yourself and maybe choose a value of 150 ohms: the result is a resistor that varies from 147.8 ohms to 149.8 ohms.

Given tolerances and that expectations are sometimes more flexible after a little thinking, does this offer a solution?

I still think this is an XY problem.